# Pyspark RDD aggregate different value fields differently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, rdd

This is a pretty open ended question, but I have an RDD in this format.

```
[('2014-06', ('131313', 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 10.5 )),
('2014-07', ('246655', 636636.53, .53252, 5252.112, 5242.23)),
('2014-06', ('131232', 1, 2, 4.5, 5.5)),
('2014-07', ('131322464', 536363.6363, 536336.6363, 3563.63636, 9.6464464646464646))]
```

I want to group by and aggregate each of the values differently by the key. For example for the key `'2014-06'`  I want to get the count of the first value field i.e `'131313'` and the average for the other fields `5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 10.5` for the key `'2014-06'`.

So the result for the above simple example for key `'2014-06'` would be `('2014-06', (2, 3.25, 5.5, 8))`.

What would be the best method to do this for an RDD? **I cannot use any Spark SQL expressions or functions only RDD functions.**

I was thinking about doing something with mapValues and using some other function but I am having some trouble formulating this function.

I know this questions is pretty open ended so please let me know if you have any more questions.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use **map()** method to convert the first value to 1 (for record counting) and then use **reduceByKey()** to sum each value with the same key. finally, use **mapValues()** to calculate the mean values except the first one which is the count(keep as-is).

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], (1, *x[1][1:]))) \
   .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: tuple([x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(x))])) \
   .mapValues(lambda x: (x[0], *[ e/x[0] for e in x[1:]]))
```

**After map():**

```
[('2014-06', (1, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 10.5)),
 ('2014-07', (1, 636636.53, 0.53252, 5252.112, 5242.23)),
 ('2014-06', (1, 1, 2, 4.5, 5.5)),
 ('2014-07', (1, 536363.6363, 536336.6363, 3563.63636, 9.646446464646464))]
```

**After reduceByKey():**

```
[('2014-06', (2, 6.5, 8.5, 12.0, 16.0)),
 ('2014-07',
  (2, 1173000.1663000002, 536337.16882, 8815.74836, 5251.876446464646))]
```

**After mapValues():**

```
[('2014-06', (2, 3.25, 4.25, 6.0, 8.0)),
 ('2014-07',
  (2, 586500.0831500001, 268168.58441, 4407.87418, 2625.938223232323))]
```

Comment: Hmm actually this doesn't seem to work for me on the data base I used, it creates strings rather than do the things you outlined

Comment: @mrsquid, from what the example data your supplied, it's unlikely that these RDD methods will be doing string operations.

Comment: The problem is with the first map after the first map it goes from looking like this [('2014-6', ('2355134', 68.0, 66.0, 189.0, 6.0))] to looking like this [('2355134', (1, '0', '1', '4'))]. I think the indices are not properly specified

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this, are you sure you are running the right code? if RDD element is like `('2014-6', ('2355134', 68.0, 66.0, 189.0, 6.0))`, then x[0] is `2014-06`, '2355134' is `x[1][0]`.

Comment: Yeah I'm really sorry it was my bad. The indices were different in the original data set compared to the example I gave, so far the code works perfectly. Again my bad

Answer (score 1):

@jxc solution does what you need but here is another way of doing it.

You can use [`aggregateByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.aggregateByKey). This function takes two functions `seqFunc`, `combFunc` and an accumulator value called neutral zero value.

```
zero_value = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
d = rdd.aggregateByKey(zero_value, lambda x, y: (1, *y[1:]),
                       lambda x, y: tuple(map(add, x, y))
                       ) \
    .mapValues(lambda v: (v[0], *[i / v[0] for i in v[1:]])) \
```

First lambda expression converts each value by replacing the first string field by integer `1` (counting for one occurrence). 
The second lambda expression merges two values by adding two lists.

After this aggregation, we just need to divide elements of each value list by the first element which gives the average.

Output:

```
[('2014-06', (2, 3.25, 4.25, 6.0, 8.0)), ('2014-07', (2, 586500.0831500001, 268168.58441, 4407.87418, 2625.938223232323))]
```

Comment: Hmm actually the count doesn't seem to work, it just gives two for each key even if there are hundreds of different values for that key.

Comment: @mrsquid Are you sure? Just tested it with more than two key-values and it gives the correct count... Can you give an example?

Comment: Let me see if I can, I am unsure as to why this does not work on the full data set. The logic is sound and it looks the same as the above version except with aggregateByKey instead...

Comment: @mrsquid, the issue was from the seqFunc which is designed to do the aggregate inside a partition. function `lambda x, y: (1, *y[1:])` does not do any aggregation, it keeps only one element for each key and discard others. that's why you lost many values. the simplest way to test this is as I mentioned from a comment I deleted, for the given example, 4 elements with 2 keys, move the data to the same partition, i.e. run rdd.repartition(1).aggregateByKey(..).  this method is only useful when the same key shows in the same partition at most once which is impractical for any big data projects.